# Parallelizing over a Map in Spark SQL's Java API

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Java 11 here using Spark SQL's **Java API** (not Scala!). I am trying to convert a `Map<String,String>` into a `Dataset<Row>` that have 2 String columns. My best attempt is:

```
public Dataset<Row> createKeyValueDataFrame(Map<String,String> dfMap, String keyColName, String valueColName) {

    JavaSparkContext sparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(sparkSession.sparkContext());

    JavaRDD<Row> rdd = sparkContext.parallelize(Arrays.asList(dfMap.entrySet().toArray()))
        .map(entry -> RowFactory.create(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));

    StructType schema = new StructType()
        .add(keyColName, DataTypes.StringType)
        .add(valueColName, DataTypes.StringType);

    return sparkSession.createDataFrame(rdd, schema);

}
```

However I'm getting compiler errors on `entry.getKey()` and `entry.getValue()`. Can anyone spot why I'm getting these errors and help me figure out what the fix is? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the error that the compiler is showing?

Comment: Its 2 compiler errors, one for `getKey()` and the other for `getValue()`, but it is the same error for both: `Cannot resolve method 'getKey' in 'Object'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is when you are doing

```java
Arrays.asList(
  dfMap         // Map<String,String>
    .entrySet() // Set<Map.Entry<String,String>>
    .toArray()  // Object[]
)
```

So, when try to do

```java
sparkContext.parallelize(Arrays.asList(dfMap.entrySet().toArray()))
```

The return of that call is `JavaRDD<Object>`. That's why the compiler is showing `Cannot resolve method 'getKey' in 'Object'`, because when you call `map`, it infers that the lambda parameter is an `Object`.

Not sure what you are exactly trying to do with this piece of code. The method `entrySet()` will return a `Set` of `Map.Entry` which represent a key-value pair. If you just need to convert that to a `List` of key-value pair, you should replace

```java
Arrays.asList(dfMap.entrySet().toArray())
```

for

```java
new ArrayList<>(dfMap.entrySet())
```